# Difference between 24 bit and 32 bit addressing mode in QSPI flash

Tags: memory, flash, flash-memories, nand-flash

I would like to know the difference between 24-bit and 32-bit QSPI flash? why 24-bit address is used in flash?

Comment: Which QSPI chip? What does the datasheet tell about this? Have you compared 24-bit and 32-bit addressing modes?

Comment: The difference is 8 bit and 8 bits is the usual increment that memory chip tech jumps in so before 24 bits was available, a lot of devices would have been 16 bit addressing but who really cares and why?

Comment: QSPI Flash :- S25FL128S/S25FL256S. Datasheet didn't explain the use of addressing 24-bit and 32-bit mode. @Justme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

24 bits can address 16 megabytes. When a larger chip is made like 32 megabyte chip it must be addressed via 32 bits address. It might still have the 24-bit command to allow use of new and larger chips in older systems supporting only 24-bit commands. Also when the speed of the QSPI bus goes high enough, the 24-bit address can be sent with dummy padding bytes to allow time for the chip to fetch the data, but it can then use the faster bus to transfer it.

Comment: what does it mean, "24 bits can address 16 megabytes"? 24 bits can address more than 16MB.!

Comment: @SriGaneshD 24 bits can address 2^24 = 16777216 units (often bytes, sometimes larger words). Using the relevant traditional (non-SI) system, one megabyte is 1024 (2^10) kilobytes and one kilobyte is 1024 (2^10) bytes. Using that convention, it takes 20 bits to address each byte in one megabyte and thus 24 bits can address 16 (2^4) megabytes. These days, the standard is to use mebibyte (MiB) to avoid confusion with SI prefixes, but the context makes Justme's usage clear IMO. See [Binary Prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)

Comment: @SriGaneshD How much in your opinion 24 bits can address then? I don't think you will find many people agreeing with you though.

Comment: Ya. Agree with your point.@Justme